# set maximum value for c3js scatter chart plot size

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, c3.js

I am building a scatter chart by C3js, the chat's plots' size with depends on it's own value, i have done the size changing method but the thing when the number goes to big the one big plot will fill the whole chart.

How may I set a max value for the scatter chart's plots?

```
point: {
        r: function(d) {
            return d.value * 0.01
        },
        focus: {
            expand: {
             enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
```

I belive there's should be something i can do to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can use scale in your method:-

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([minValue, maxValue])
                    .range([minR, maxR]);
```

in above lines provide the minValue and maxValue i.e. the minimum and maximum value of  array which you providing to c3 lib to draw the chart.
and minR and maxR: provide the minimum radius you want and maximum scale.
now use this as below:-

```
var output=scale(input);
```

now this output will be within the range you mentioned while you were defining the scale. 
you can code like this:-

```
point: {
        r: function(d) {
            return scale(d.value);
        },
        focus: {
            expand: {
             enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: How may implement an Array in to the .domain value?  i tried .domain([array[0], array[1]]) but no luck